# How to "cut" Date by half month

Tags: r

Function "cut" has provided a easy way to cut date-data by "month", "week", "quarter", But I want to cut date-data by half-month. Is there a easy way to do that?

Comment: What is a "half-month" when the month has 31 days?  And it would be real nice if you can show a reproducible example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Close vote for lack of clarity.

Comment: @RichardScriven I vote for "all odd-numbered days are half A and the even-numbered days are half B"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean half-month in the sense of astronomy in which case days 1-15 belong to the first half of the month and 16+ to the second and where successive half months are denoted by A, B, C, ..., Y (except for I) then create some test data `x` and then compute its POSIXlt representation so that we can pick off year (represented as no of years since 1900), month (represented as 0, 1, ..., 11) and day of month (1, 2, 3, ...).  We then compute the index of the half-month in `LETTERS[-9]` and prepend the year to that.  Note that this already gives a grouping vector and you don't need to use `cut` at all.

```
x <- as.Date("2000-01-01") + seq(0, 100, 15) # test data
x
## [1] "2000-01-01" "2000-01-16" "2000-01-31" "2000-02-15" "2000-03-01"
## [6] "2000-03-16" "2000-03-31"

lt <- as.POSIXlt(x)
paste0(lt$year+1900, LETTERS[-9][2*lt$mon + 1 + (lt$mday > 15)])
## [1] "2000A" "2000B" "2000B" "2000C" "2000E" "2000F" "2000F"
```

Note that for the future that SO questions should have complete examples including test input and expected output.